# 1901 Boxer Protocol settlement to Norway

Tags: china, norway

The Boxer Protocol was the settlement made in 1901 after the [Boxer Rebellion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxer_rebellion) in China. The victors, consisting of eight major Western powers, got large indemnities from the Chinese government, as well as other concessions.

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxer_Protocol) on the protocol, however, Norway got 0.025% (or maybe 0.0025%, the article is unclear) of the indemnity. The article does not say why, or whether the debt was waived by Norway later. So my questions are:

- Why was Norway included in the settlement?
- Was the money eventually paid in full? If not, why not?

Note: Norway shared a King and foreign policy with Sweden until 1905. It had independence in most domestic affairs, but this looks a lot like foreign affairs and hence it might be that the Norwegian part followed from some Swedish involvement. My question still stands, though.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely the indemnity was meant to compensate the various nations for the loss of lives of their citizens and property, pro-rated roughly to the amount of each country lost.

I can't find exact records of deaths, but there were Norwegian citizens in China during the rebellion. The [China Inland Mission](http://www.omf.org/omf/us/resources__1/omf_archives/china_inland_mission_stories) was proselytizing in rural China at the time, and many of their missionaries were hunted down and killed. At least [one member was Norwegian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2000/aug/05/china.johngittings), although she escaped. There were likely more who weren't so fortunate. There were also [quite a few Swedes](http://www.cmalliance.org/about/history/in-the-line-of-fire/boxer-rebellion) in China doing the same kind of work. The same source says 41 of them were killed, along with 15 children.

The besieged foriegn quarter of Peking [also contained Norwegians](http://www.shsu.edu/~his_ncp/bxr2.html).

Comment: Thanks! I agree deaths of missionaries is a likely explanation. Still, if anyone have more specific answers (and also answers to the second point), I'd be grateful for that as well :-)